# Jensen's Formula application $f(z)$ has no zeros on $|z|=r, r<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, complex-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I am reading the Balazard Saias and Yor paper where he defines,
$s=s(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$ and $$f(z)=(s-1)\zeta(s)$$ where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function.Then by Jensen's formula we have for $f(0)\neq 0$ and $r<1$,
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}log\ |f(re^{i\theta})|d\theta=log\ |f(0)|+\sum_{|\alpha|<r,f(\alpha)=0} log \ \frac{r}{|\alpha|}$$

For applying Jensen's formula we need that $f(z)$ has no zeros on $|z|=r$.

**Question** Show that $f(z)$ has no zeros on $|z|=r$, $r<1$.

**Attempt**
$$f(z)=(s-1)\zeta(s)$$
$$f(z)= \frac{z}{1-z}\zeta(\frac{1}{1-z})$$
Since $|z|=r$ so write $z=re^{i\theta}$
$$\zeta(\frac{1}{1-z})= \zeta(\frac{1}{1-re^{i\theta}})    $$
$$\zeta(\frac{1}{1-z})= \zeta(\frac{1}{1-rcos\theta-irsin\theta})    $$
$$\zeta(\frac{1}{1-z})= \zeta(\frac{1-rcos\theta+irsin\theta}{(1-rcos\theta)^2+r^2sin^2\theta})    $$
$$\zeta(\frac{1}{1-z})= \zeta(\frac{1-rcos\theta+irsin\theta}{r^2-2rcos\theta+1})    $$
How to show that $f(re^{i\theta})\neq 0$ on $|z|=r, r<1$?.

Comment: I am not that familiar with the zeta function, but are the authors assuming the Riemann hypothesis? It can be shown that the real part of s is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @shortmanikos No I am not assuming the Riemann hypothesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jensen's theorem is valid even if $f$ has zeroes on the circle $|z|=r$ (in practice since such circles are discrete, one avoids them easily in the usual applications of Jensen which is to count zeros in open discs)

The proof is standard assuming the result first without zeroes; then the number of zeroes on the circle $|z|=r$ is finite ($f$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $|z|=r$ in Jensen), hence let them be $a_1,..a_n, |a_k|=r$ counted with multiplicity.

Hence $f=(z-a_1)..(z-a_n)g$ with $g$ same zeroes as $f$ except those on the circle and $\log |f|=\log |g|+\log |z-a_1|+...\log |z-a_k|$

But now applying Jensen for $g$, using the easy to prove fact that $\int_0^{2\pi}\log |r(e^{i\theta}-e^{i\theta_0})|d\theta=2\pi \log r$, the fact that $|\log f(0)|=n\log r+|\log g(0)|$ and the observation that $\log r/|a_k|=0$ gives the result.

Comment: Thank you so much for an awesome and simple answer. What do you mean by saying that the circles are discrete? Can you please give me a reference for using jensen formula with zeroes on the cricle $|z|=r$.

Comment: The radiuses of circles where $f$ has zeroes form a discrete set in the domain of $f$ (may accumulate only at the boundary); not sure of the second question - jensen is used to count zeroes (if the function has no zeroes in a disc, jensen is trivially the mean value theorem for harmonic functions so is uninteresting) and usually the few zeroes on a circle are irrelevant as we saw above - they contribute nothing in the sum and only their modulus counts in the logarithm of $f$ at zero; note that also $f(0) \ne 0$ is another standard assumption that is corrected by a logarithmic term if it fails

Comment: Thanks a lot. How is no. of zeroes on the circle is finite?

Comment: the function is analytic in a neighborhood of the circle and not identically zero (circle is compact so any infinite set of points there has accumulation points etc); the heart of the Balazard et others paper is to show that one can extend the Jensen formula to the radial limit of $f$ using that $f$ is in a Hardy space so it has $BSO$ decomposition, the singular factor is trivial etc

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: happy to help when questions are well-posed and clear

Comment: Thanks a lot. You were very helpful. I am giving your answer a checkmark. Please tell me which book to read for Jensen's and balazard?

Comment: I would say that the references in Balazard (eg Hoffman's book for Hardy spaces and Titchmarsh Theory of Functions for Jensen) are excellent

Comment: Thanks a ton Sir. I am giving your answer a check mark. Thanks again. Please help me in future as well.

Comment: In Balazard paper, why do we need the function in the Hardy space?

Comment: otherwise, it is not (generally) true that Jensen holds for the radial function on the circle

Comment: But in Jensen's formula it is not given that we should have a function in Hardy space?

Comment: of course not if the function is analytic on the disc $|z| \le r$ (which means in a slightly larger disc); however here remember we want to apply Jensen for $f^*$ which is the radial limit (a.e.) of $f$ on the circle of radius $1$ and $f$ cannot be extended analytically in a neighborhood of $1$ (on the circle) so there is no larger disc of analyticity;

Comment: Thanks a lot. Which book did you follow for RZ? I am new to RZ. Please recommend me some book

Comment: Titchmarsh bible is a must at least for reference; hard to say otherwise, depends on what you know etc; for RH, the Broughan two volume set about equivalences is a must

Comment: Kevin Broughan is good? Any video lectures?

Comment: have no idea about video lectures; the Broughan book is a reference book that collects tons of material

Comment: Thanks a ton. Bbye.

Answer (score 0):

The question is equivalent to showing that $\zeta(s)\ne0$ for $|s|<1$.

- When $\Re s\le 0$, we know that $\zeta(s)$ has only trivial zeros at $s=-2,-4,-6,\dots$, by the functional equation for $\zeta(s)$.
- When $\Re s>0$, we can use the fact that
  $$
  \sum_{\substack{\rho \\ \zeta(\rho)=0 \\ 0<\Re\rho<1}} \Re\frac1\rho = \frac{C_0}2+1-\frac12\log4\pi\approx0.0231
  $$
  to show that $\zeta(s)$ has no nontrivial zeros $\rho$ with $|\Im\rho|\le6.5$. (See for example Exercise 2 in Section 10.2 of Montgomery and Vaughan's *Multiplicative Number Theory I. Classical Theory*.)

Together these two results prove the desired statement and then some.

Comment: How is the question equivalent to showing that $\zeta(s)\neq 0$ for $|s|<1$?

Comment: Please reply. How is the question equivalent to showing that $\zeta(s)\neq 0$ for $|s|<1$?

Comment: Should it be $\zeta(s)\neq 0$ for $|z|<1$?

Comment: How is the question equivalent to showing that $\zeta(s)\neq 0 $ for $|s|<1$?

Comment: @ananditakumari: One question is sufficient. The users of this site are volunteers with lives of our own, and are under no obligation to fulfill your wishes on your timetable. Asking the same question four times, much less in such a short time span, comes across as demanding and rude.—I hope you will eventually see that "$f(z)\ne0$ for $|z|=r,r<1$" is the same as "$f(z)\ne0$ for $|z|<1$" which is the same as $\zeta(s)\ne0$ for $|s|<1$ (since the zeros of $s-1$ are obvious). It probably causes some confusion that you are using both $s$ and $z$ interchangeably.

Comment: I am sorry. But how $f(z)\neq 0$ for $|z|<1$ is same as $\zeta(s)\neq 0$ for $|s|<1$. How do we get $|s|<1$?

Comment: @GregMartin From what I understood of the question $s$ is a function of $z$, namely $ s = s(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}$. So there are values of $ z $ with $ |z| < 1 $ and $ s(z) > 1 $

Comment: @shortmanikos So what about the answer to the question?